# Pyinstaller-spacy : "OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'es_core_news_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a Python package or a valid path to a data directory."

Tags: pyinstaller, spacy

I did an application with Tkinter and this has a function based in spacy. When a built the executable file using Pyinstaller I ran `pyinstaller simple.py --additional-hooks-dir=.`. My file hook collect the necessary packages also the pre-trained language spacy model  `es_cores_news_sm` with the follow code:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_all

# ----------------------------- SPACY -----------------------------
data = collect_all("spacy")

datas = data[0]
binaries = data[1]
hiddenimports = data[2]

from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files

datas += collect_data_files("es_core_news_sm")
```

The executable was create and open well. When I use the function based in spacy we obtain the follow error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
  File "simple.py", line 152, in calcular
  File "predictors.py", line 16, in cash_pred
  File "utils.py", line 41, in clean_text
  File "spacy/__init__.py", line 47, in load
  File "spacy/util.py", line 329, in load_model
OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'es_core_news_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

Originally, I installed in my pip environment the pre-trained model with `python -m spacy download es_core_news_sm`. How can I collect well this pre-trained model well in Pyinstaller?

Comment: You have to tell PyInstaller to pick up the model. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66495437/cant-find-spacy-model-when-packaging-with-pyinstaller

Comment: @polm23 I try using ` a = Analysis(datas= [ ('spacy/es_core_news_sm, 'spacy' ) ], )` but it not works. Also we do this before with `datas += collect_data_files("es_core_news_sm")`