# Packaging SpaCy Model with Pyinstaller: E050 Can't find model

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, spacy-3

I'm using Pyinstaller to pack my python spacy code. I'm using the de_core_news_sm and installed it via pip.
The normal script performs as expected but as soon as it is packaged with pyinstaller it can not find the model `[E050] Can't find model 'de_core_news_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.`
i got for each hook a file:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_all

# ----------------------------- blis -----------------------------
data = collect_all('blis')
datas = data[0]
binaries = data[1]
hiddenimports = data[2]
```

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_all

# ----------------------------- cymen -----------------------------
data = collect_all('cymem')
datas = data[0]
binaries = data[1]
hiddenimports = data[2]
```

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files
datas = collect_data_files("de_core_news_sm")
```

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_all

# ----------------------------- preshed -----------------------------
data = collect_all('preshed')
datas = data[0]
binaries = data[1]
hiddenimports = data[2]
```

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_all

# ----------------------------- SPACY -----------------------------
data = collect_all('spacy')
datas = data[0]
binaries = data[1]
hiddenimports = data[2]
```

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_all

# ----------------------------- thinc -----------------------------
data = collect_all('thinc')
datas = data[0]
binaries = data[1]
hiddenimports = data[2]
```

and i use the following pyinstaller command:

```
pyinstaller script.py --hidden-import cmath --hidden-import srsly.msgpack.util
```

in this post [1]: [Can't find SpaCy model when packaging with PyInstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66495437/cant-find-spacy-model-when-packaging-with-pyinstaller/66523115#66523115)

the is the solution with the added data files from modules. So how must i change my code in my script.py runtime file and how must i change the hook files?

BTW i'm using: spacy 3.0.6, pyinstaller 4.3 and python 3.8.0 in my virtual environment.

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding this to my runtime scripts solve the problem. Instead of loading it as a module i'm loading my model from the path

```
from pathlib import Path
bundle_dir = Path(__file__).parent.absolute()
source_nlp = spacy.load(bundle_dir / "de_core_news_sm")
```

And the hook file to collect all de_core_news_sm data

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files
datas = collect_data_files("de_core_news_sm")
```

Comment: Good answer! One should also make sure to choose the correct model subfolder as shown here: https://spacy.io/usage/models#download-manual